# Validate Email Or Number in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a sign in form where userid is email id of users or unique id given by us i.e in integer.

So i want regex for that text box to validate email or Id.

Means.

if someone enters

`abc@abc.com`
or
`1024`
then it is valid

and if someone is entering anything other than email or integer than it should show as invalid.

Thanks...

Comment: what is a valid email format for you?

Comment: anything which is email i.e it might be abc@localhost or abc@google.com anything wich is email

Comment: standard email sp charcters i.e underscore or `.`

Comment: `^(?:[\w.]+@[\w.]+\.\w{2,4}|\d+)$`

Comment: can u pls explain avi?

Comment: @NetMaster see the explanation at the right side in [this](http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/3) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:[\w.]+@[\w.]+|\d+)$
```

You can try this.Though Your requirements are not very clear.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/4

Comment: Request you to pls explain

Comment: @NetMaster it says (any character for the character class `[\w.]` more than one time ,then `@` the again any charcter from `[\w.]` more than 1 time)or any integrer.`\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: @vks recheck your regex.

Comment: it also matches `123` in `foo123`

Comment: WHERE IS THE OR CASE BRO I MEAN THAT THING TO ACCEPT INTEGER OR IF NOT INTEGER THAN EMAIL

Comment: @NetMaster `|\d+` this part does that for you.Please check the demo.Try there.Also Check your `CAPS LOCK`.

Comment: YUP DONE UNDERSTOOD DIDN'T NOTICED THE PIPE BEFORE..:P tHANKS

Comment: HEY GUYS CAN U PLS MODIFY THIS ANGULAR EMAIL REGEX TO ACCEPT NUMBER AS OR `/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i `

Comment: AS SIMPLE AS CAKE GREAT WORK APPRECIATE YOU VKS